# SQL Server Geography datatype nearest point on line

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, gis

I am trying to build a query, but I am having some difficulty.

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a table that includes, among other fields, a geography field that describes road segments. (This data has been imported from TIGER/Line data from the U.S. Census.)

I have another fixed point describing a user's location. I want to find the closest road segment in the database to that point, but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Furthermore, I want to find the closest point on that segment to the user location point. This is what I want to select and return back in my query.

Does anyone have any experience with the geography/geometry functionality that can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add some field type information.   For example, you have a fixed point to describe the user's location, is this a Longitude and Latitude coordinate pair?   I have experience with the geography functions, but need more details...

Comment: I'm providing this from my application, so I'm passing in an argument. I'm fine with pretty much whatever data type is necessary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can store your objects in a `GEOGRAPHY` column and create a `SPATIAL INDEX` over this column.

Unfortunately, `SQL Server` implements spatial indexes by tiling the surface and storing the tile identifiers in a plain `B-Tree` index, so plain `ORDER BY STDistance` won't work (well, it will work but won't use the index).

Instead, you'll have to make a query similar to this:

```
DECLARE @mypoint GEOGRAPHY
SET @mypoint = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(@mylat, @mylon)', 4326);

WITH    num (distance) AS
        (
        SELECT  1000
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  distance + 1000
        FROM    num
        WHERE   distance <= 50000
        )
SELECT  TOP 1 m.*
FROM    num
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   myroad.STDistance(@mypoint) <= distance
        ORDER BY
                STDistance(@mypoint)
        ) m
```

This way, `SQL Server` will first search roads within `1` kilometer from your point, then within `2` kilometers, etc., each time using the index.

**Update:**

If you have multiple points in a table and want to find the closest point for each of them:

```
WITH    num (distance) AS
        (
        SELECT  1000
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  distance + 1000
        FROM    num
        WHERE   distance <= 50000
        )
SELECT  mp.mypoint, m.*
FROM    @mypoints mp
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 m.*
        FROM    num
        CROSS APPLY
                (
                SELECT  TOP 1 *
                FROM    mytable
                WHERE   myroad.STDistance(@mypoint) <= distance
                ORDER BY
                        STDistance(@mypoint)
                ) m
        ) m
```

Comment: Best answer I think I've ever encountered on StackOverflow. Thanks for letting me know not to just `ORDER BY`, which is probably what I would have ended up implementing.

Comment: hi. I'm not sure if @Pure Krome figured it out, but I can't seem to get it. *Cross Apply my query to @myPoints* ?? I don't get it :( Can you please update your answer, please???

Comment: Great answer, but doesn't answer the whole OP question. Once you have the closest road what is the point on that road which is closest to the point?

Comment: Just found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2010/11/19/a-short-discussion-on-the-shortestlineto-method.aspx which will give you this.

Answer (score -1):

How are your road segments stored?  lat and long?  if so, you can convert them to radians, and do the math:

- http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.mssql.html
- http://www.petefreitag.com/item/622.cfm
- http://johndyer.name/post/2005/07/11/LatitudeLongitude-Distance-Calculation-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: The segments are stored in the Geography data type.