# How to use one Mysql query instead of query inside array loop?

Tags: php, mysql

The query below is currently within a loop(in PHP) that takes latitude, longitude, and id inputs from 3 different arrays. For each position/key in the array the nearest geographical place is selected from the table using the query below.

As the size of the array is typically around 500, so 500 sets of inputs, for which a nearest geographical position needs to be found it is taking some time.

My question: Is there any way to use one query using the input arrays from php at once, and selecting a set of all the nearest geographical positions for each array key?

```
$sql="SELECT 
id, d, tolon, tolat, du,
       ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat1) ) 
              * cos( radians( travel.tolat ) ) 
              * cos( radians( travel.tolon) - radians($lon1) ) 
              + sin( radians($lat1) ) 
              * sin( radians( travel.tolat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM travel 
WHERE userid = $id AND tolon > $lonlow AND tolon < $lonhigh AND tolat > $latlow AND tolat < $lathigh
having distance < $maxdistance ORDER BY distance
";
```

Comment: worse case solution would be a UNION, but some one will post a better idea im sure. Have you tried ..OR..

Comment: I'd try inserting the array into a temp table and then a regular join could be used. At least it's a starting point

Comment: @ ingo Well it's not easy to join them since the join is  defined by the minimum distance between geographical coordinates in the two tables, which are calculated by a formula.

Comment: You don't need a loop if your database supports LATERAL query. Unfortunately, the database that I know that has LATERAL functionality are DB2 and SQL Server. In SQL Server it's called CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY. Postgresql has plan to support LATERAL too. See example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035312/sql-server-geography-datatype-nearest-point-on-line An OUTER APPLY walkthrough http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/04/outer-apply-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll do much better than a bunch of unions, although adding a `limit 1` is a good idea if you only need the closest. A bunch of unions will be a very long sql string, and there's limits you may hit(`max packet size` is the setting, i believe). You would have to maybe chunk 100 or so unions at a time.

You stand to gain *a lot* if the table had indexes designed for this type of query. mysql has suport for `spatial indexes` that you should seriously consider looking into because regular indexes dont perform very well for this use case.

Comment: In addition to this answer I used unique values from the arrays to limit the number of records required from the database.